# Navigation bar not to be seen when UITableViewController is pushed onto the navigation stack

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller

Code in the view controller which is currently on a navigation controller stack. Now I want to push a `UITableViewContoller` onto the navigation stack. I'm using the following code:

```
let destinationVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "formTableVC") as! FormTableViewController

self.navigationController?.pushViewController(destinationVC, animated: true)
```

The `UITableViewContoller` shows up but the navigation bar is not shown. How to solve this issue? I want the design which has been carried forward to all the previous view controllers to be shown in the `UITableViewContoller`'s navigation bar as well. Any help would be greatly appreciated. thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following code to viewDidLoad function of UITableViewContoller(FormTableViewController) 
 Class

`self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: false)`